# remove the need for main_app prefix in path helpers in main app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-engines

I've got an isolated, mountable rails engine which mounts itself in a namespace that is already declared in the host application. Here's how it looks more or less:

routes.rb in the plugin:

```
# my_engine/config/routes.rb 
MyEngine::Engine.routes.draw do
  namespace :admin do
    resources :some_resource
  end
end
```

And the appropriate snippet from the host app's routes.rb:

```
# config/routes.rb
mount MyEngine::Engine, at: "/"

namespace :admin do
  resources :host_resource
end
```

I'm mounting the engine at `/` since there are some routes in the engine that should be available there, and the admin namespaces overlap is intentional.

These routes generates several path helpers, including `my_engine.admin_some_resources_path` and what I would expect to be `admin_host_resources_path`. The latter is what doesn't work.

Assume there's a controller in the main application that is declared so:

```
# app/controllers/admin/application_controller.rb
class Admin::ApplicationController < ApplicationController
  layout 'admin'
end
```

And the engine's AdminController is declared in such a way as to inherit from it:

```
# my_engine/app/controlles/admin/application_controller.rb
class MyEngine::Admin::ApplicationController < Admin::ApplicationController
end
```

So far, all that works as expected. Now, assume that in the main application's `admin` layout, referenced from the Admin::ApplicationController, I try to use something essentially like:

```
# app/views/layouts/admin.html.erb
<%= link_to "Host resources", admin_host_resources_path %>
<%= link_to "Plugin's resources", my_engine.admin_some_resources_path %>
```

This works fine when I load a path like '/admin/host_resources' - it renders the admin layout from the main application no problem. When opening the path '/admin/some_resources' - which goes into the plugin - it stops working complaining that `admin_host_resources_path` was not found. It starts working when I change it to this:

```
# app/views/layouts/admin.html.erb
<%= link_to "Host resources", main_app.admin_host_resources_path %>
<%= link_to "Plugin's resources", my_engine.admin_some_resources_path %>
```

Which is not what I want, nor is it what I expect. Also I've seen enough rails plugins to know that this shouldn't be necessary, but after reading the Engines documentation I'm still at a loss. I've also scoured Stack, but to no avail. My question is: **how to include the main_app helpers so that the prefix main_app is no longer needed**?

It's worth noting that the views for host_resource are in the main application itself, while the views for some_resource are in the engine. This shouldn't matter though, since the view which doesn't work is the `admin` layout in the main application.

Also excuse the heavily anonymised code, but this is required of me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this in your controller:

```
helper Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

Comment: Thank you, it works with my Rails 6 app and engine!

Comment: This "works" for us, in that it fixes page from erroring with "NameError: undefined local variable or method ..._path", but the paths are now prefixed with the engine path, `/admin/companies/1/my_engine/admin/companies/1` instead of `/admin/companies/1`, any ideas on how to fix that?

Answer (score 3):

I found an answer to my question here: http://candland.net/2012/04/17/rails-routes-used-in-an-isolated-engine/

What I needed to do was to specify a helper like this in the engine:

```
module MyEngine
  module ApplicationHelper
    def method_missing method, *args, &block
      if method.to_s.end_with?('_path') or method.to_s.end_with?('_url')
        if main_app.respond_to?(method)
          main_app.send(method, *args)
        else
          super
        end
      else
        super
      end
    end

    def respond_to?(method)
      if method.to_s.end_with?('_path') or method.to_s.end_with?('_url')
        if main_app.respond_to?(method)
          true
        else
          super
        end
      else
        super
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then make sure it is loaded when the engine is loaded by adding this to my engine class:

```
initializer 'my_engine.action_controller' do |app|
  ActiveSupport.on_load :action_controller do
    helper MyEngine::ApplicationHelper
  end
end
```

Thanks to this the paths that can be served by the engine are served by the engine, and everything else is sent to the main_app helper.